# RPI won't load shared libraries

Tags: c++, linux, compilation, shared-libraries, raspberry-pi3

RPI won't load shared libraries

```
error while loading shared libraries: libntcore.so : cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

When compiled, everything works fine, but when I try to execute, the error pops.

What I have tried :

- run `ldconfig`
- check if my file is in the right place (`/usr/lib`)
- set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `:/usr/lib` by running 
  `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib`

By the way, I am using a NOOBS os.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/), [Internet of Things Stack Exchange](http://iot.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: add an `export ` in front of your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=` statement. That may help. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks jww, I'll check those out!

Comment: Might want to check the output of `ldd`.